# How to get count in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a 2 tables as follows

```
| Id |   email |
|----|---------|
|  1 | a@a.com |
|  2 | b@b.com |
|  3 | a@a.com |
|  4 | b@b.com |
|  5 | c@c.com |
|  6 | d@d.com |
|  7 | b@b.com |
```

-

```
| Id | names |
|----|-------|
|  1 |  audi |
|  2 |  ford |
|  3 |  ford |
|  4 |  ford |
|  5 |  audi |
|  6 |  benz |
|  7 |   bmw |
|  1 |   bmw |
|  2 |  audi |
```

Now, I want to display the columns of `email,count of email and ReqType`, where ReqType column shows as `required` if names table contains either "Audi or ford" else `"Not-Req"`

My query is:

```
select  
    email, count(email) as Email,
    case
       when t2.names in ('Audi', 'ford')
          then 'req'
          else 'Not-req'
    end as 'ReqType'
from
    t1
inner join      
    t2 on t1.Id = t2.Id
group by     
    email, names
```

But it is showing as:

```
|   email | Email | ReqType |
|---------|-------|---------|
| a@a.com |     1 |     req |
| a@a.com |     1 | Not-req |
| a@a.com |     1 |     req |
| b@b.com |     1 |     req |
| b@b.com |     1 | Not-req |
| b@b.com |     2 |     req |
| c@c.com |     1 |     req |
| d@d.com |     1 | Not-req |
```

Required output is

```
|   email | Email | ReqType |
|---------|-------|---------|
| a@a.com |     2 |     req |
| a@a.com |     1 | Not-req |
| b@b.com |     3 |     req |
| b@b.com |     1 | Not-req |
| c@c.com |     1 |     req |
| d@d.com |     1 | Not-req |
```

How to achieve this?

[SqlDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f96df/1)

Comment: Group by reqtype instead of names.

Answer (score 1):

Create your ReqType field at the same level as your actual columns, then do your count.

```
SELECT
    [email],
    COUNT([email]) AS [Email],
    [ReqType]
FROM
    (
    select          
        email,
        case when t2.names in ('Audi','ford') then 
            'req'
        else
            'Not-req'
        end 
        as 'ReqType'
    from
        t1
        inner join t2 on t1.Id = t2.Id
    ) DerivedWithReqType
GROUP BY
    [email],
    [ReqType]
```

Comment: Have you checked out the quer, for some reason it is giving me an error @LDMJoe

Comment: @DheerajPatnaik Your fiddle throws an error because you are targeting mysql 5.6.  Your question is tagged with sql-server, so my query is MSSQL.

Answer (score 1):

@jarlh is right:

```
select email,
        count(email) as Email,
        case when t2.names in ('Audi','ford')
                then 'req'
                else 'Not-req'
            end as 'ReqType'
    from t1
      inner join t2 on t1.Id = t2.Id
    group by email, case when t2.names in ('Audi','ford')
                            then 'req'
                            else 'Not-req'
                        end
```